# SQL Query Connected Excel Report Hanging on Saving

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, sql

I have a MS Excel 17 sheet with multiple SQLDB queries connected for reporting. This is called by a python script that opens, puts in the PW, refreshes the queries, saves the report, and closes excel.

Sometimes, I'd say 60 percent of the time, the script performs perfectly, reaches the saving state and the sheet gets stuck on 'saving' and just hangs there causing the script to fail. The only way to exit excel at this point is to force close. This doesn't appear to generate a log in Event Viewer either, any one have suggestions on where to look next?

Thanks!

Comment: So you know for certain that, when it does hang, it's because of one function/method call in particular?

Comment: I'm not entirely positive if I'm honest, when I reload the queries in the report manually it works about 80% of the time. However, attempting to save the report can still cause it to just remain stuck in the saving state. It appears that they python refresh just makes this more likely.